# upgrading server version 18.04 to 20.04 grub boot issue, repaired, but is it now safe to use

Tags: boot, upgrade

I have a dual-boot server (two different SSDs), and followed instructions to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04
as per this page https://linuxhandbook.com/upgrade-ubuntu-server-version/ updating 18.04 first then do-release-upgrade.

All seemed ok until the restart when it would not boot at all. In rescue mode message was approx. "symbols grub_files not found"

I managed to find the community Boot-Repair iso  and the 3rd time of trying from USB got to the GUI. followed the instructions and it does now boot, but with **no login prompt**  - unless hit `<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F2>`.

Is this the "new normal"?

Then looking at /boot I have TWO versions of all 4 files (config, initrd.img, System.map, vmlunuz) with version suffixes "4.15.0-135-generic" and "5.4.0-65-generic" plus grub and grub.bak directories.

I did create a pastebin from the Boot Repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/23Sfq7wnVS

On startup it does run but I don't get any of the previous terminal massive(text) progress/status info, just "20.04" and then 3 or 4  "cloud update" lines and no login prompt.

I am a reluctant to put the server into full use without being sure it is reliable and upgraded properly.

Can you advise please?
Many thanks

Comment: solved the no login prompt, it's because Grub has a config line "quiet splash" - removing that and now see the text boot progress and completed with terminal prompt, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Having two versions of kernel files available seems dangerous tho - should I remove the older version files?